# app celery task depends of BaseClass in Celery

Tags: celery, fastapi, worker, celery-task, celerybeat

I want to create Base class for all tasks in Celery my code is

tasks/all/test.py

```py
from celery import app
from base.main import CeleryMain
    
@app.task(time_limit=10)
def test():
    task = CeleryMain.delay()
    return task
```

base/main.py

```py
from celery import app
import requests
from celery import Celery, Task
   
class CeleryMain(app.Task):
    
    abstract = True
    
    def run(self, task):
        data = task.apply_async()
        s = data.get(timeout=10, interval=0.01)
        return {'success': True, 'data': s}
    
task = CeleryMain()
app.register_task(task)
task.delay()
```

celery.py

```py
imports = (
    'tasks.all.test',
)
```

I have error:

```
celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'tasks.all.test'
```

Please help me on how to create main class for all tasks correctly without mistakes for each task Base class.

Answer (score 0):

CeleryMain= app.register_task(CeleryMain())

task = CeleryMain.run(task)
print(task.id)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).